# Problems connecting to Mysql on a docker container via PDO, but command line works

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo

A brief summary of my question:
What characteristic of my docker-compose is colliding with PDO that prevents Host -> mysql-docker via PDO, but allows Host -> mysql-docker from *all* other tools?

---

My App's config file:

```
database:
  host: mysql
  port: 3306
  name: <name>
  username: <username>
  password: <pass>
  outsideContainerConnections:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3307
```

Everything is running fine within the container, and I am able to access the database from the host using PHPStorm or Mysql on the command line.

If I run this command from the host, it connects

```
mysql --port=3307 -h 127.0.0.1 -u <username> -p
```

However, if I try to connect from php on the host, using PDO, it fails with

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

PDO DSNs I've tried:

```
mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3307;port=;dbname=<name>;&charset=utf8;
    or
mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3307;dbname=<name>;&charset=utf8;
    or
mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3307;dbname=<name>;&charset=utf8;
```

I have read about using localhost vs 127.0.0.1 to force TCP, and I am doing that here.

Here also is the relevant section of my docker-composer. Again, using command line or other tools from the host work fine, it is only PDO that seems to have an issue. For what it's worth, PDO on another container in the docker-compose network is behaving.

```
mysql:
  build: './mysql_docker'
  command: --lower_case_table_names=0
  ports:
    - '3307:3306'
  volumes:
    - ./volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ./volumes/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
  networks:
    - app-tier
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try use `host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: @Dmitry, I have just tried that and, interestingly, mysql via command line is also able to connect using 0.0.0.0. Unfortunately, PDO is giving the same 'connection refused' exception. This problem seems to be unique to PDO and I cannot yet explain why.

Comment: Do you also run your PHP application in another container? Then please share the relevant `Dockerfile` sections

Comment: I do run a php application from another container. However, for this problem I am working from the host in PHP. Would you prefer I post the whole docker-compose anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it– it's simple but hopefully a good lesson to pass on.

In one case the PHP file was being run by cron, and so it was being run locally, outside of the docker container. I had a small syntax or other error in my file so cron was having some trouble.

In order to debug this situation, I was opening the file in my web browser–and that's the kicker. The connection errors I saw in the web browser were not the same problems cron was having, because that page was being served by the docker container. Thus, the connection details had to be different. The same setup could not work both from the host and from the neighbor container.

What I learned is this; what seems like a really heady technical problem that requires lots of manual reading and research COULD be a simple bad assumption. Sometimes it's worth going back to the drawing board and sketching an outline of the situation from the ground up.

In a way that is what I did with asking this question, so thank you for the space to do so.

Answer (score -2):

try "mysql --port=3307 -h 127.0.0.1 -u  -p" from client if no

Comment: I’m afraid I do not understand your point. I am able to connect from the command line but unable to connect via PDO. Did you intentionally leave the -u parameter empty or are you implying that the username is there? Again, I am able to connect from the command line, no problems.